# Jakarta Faces 4: Auto completion with new URNs e.g. "jakarta.faces.html" not working

Tags: eclipse, jsf, facelets, jboss-tools

The described new URNs e.g.

```html
<html
    xmlns:faces="jakarta.faces"
    xmlns:ui="jakarta.faces.facelets"
    xmlns:f="jakarta.faces.core"
    xmlns:h="jakarta.faces.html"
    xmlns:pt="jakarta.faces.passthrough"
    xmlns:cc="jakarta.faces.composite"
    xmlns:yourCompositeComponents="jakarta.faces.component/libraryname"
    xmlns:yourFacesComponents="jakarta.faces.component"
    xmlns:c="jakarta.tags.core"
    xmlns:fn="jakarta.tags.functions">
    ...
</html>
```

(see [What's new in Faces 4.0?](https://balusc.omnifaces.org/2021/11/whats-new-in-faces-40.html#xmlns)) are not working with auto completion (Ctrl + Space) in Eclipse 4.28 and JBoos-Tools 4.28.0.Final. How to make it working?